# How is a for expression with multiple monads translated in scala?

Tags: scala, monads

I am reading "Programming in Scala 2nd Edition" and I have some idea about monad from a Haskell course I took. However, I do not understand why the following code "magically" works:

```
scala> val a: Option[Int] = Some(100)
a: Option[Int] = Some(100)

scala> val b = List(1, 2, 3)
b: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

for ( y <- b; x <- a ) yield x;
res5: List[Int] = List(100, 100, 100)
```

I do not understand the above because according to the book's Chapter 23.4, the `for` expression is translated to something like:

```
b flatMap ( y =>
  a map ( x => x )
)
```

I am puzzled why the above code compiles because `y => a map (x => x)` is of type `Int => Option[Int]`, while the `b.flatMap` expects a `Int => List[Something]`.

On the other hand, the following code does NOT compile (which is good otherwise I would be more lost):

```
scala> for ( x <- a; y <- b ) yield y;
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Option[?]
              for ( x <- a; y <- b ) yield y;
                          ^
```

So what is magical with the first example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> […] `b.flatMap` expects a `Int => List[Something]`.

That is not true: what it expects is an `Int => GenTraversableOnce[Something]`. (See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List, and search the page for `flatMap`.) `List[A]` is a subtype of `GenTraversableOnce[A]` by inheritance. A function of type `Int => List[Something]` can be substituded because of the covariance of the result `R` of `Function1`, which is defined as: `trait Function1[-T1, +R]`.

`Option[A]` is not a `GenTraversableOnce[A]`, but there is an implicit conversion in [Option's companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option$):  `implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A]`. `Iterable[A]` is a subtype of `GenTraversableOnce[A]`. So the for-expression will get expanded to

```
b flatMap ( y =>
  option2Iterable(a map ( x => x ))
)
```

> On the other hand, the following code does NOT compile […]

This is because `a.flatMap`, by contrast, is more specific: it really does require an `Int => Option[Something]`. (See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option, and search the page for `flatMap`.) This makes sense, since an `Option[Something]` can only hold one value, so you couldn't flatten an arbitrary `GenTraversableOnce[Something]` into it. The only thing that can successfully be flattened into an `Option[Something]` is another `Option[Something]`.

Comment: `Option` isn't a `GenTraversableOnce`

Comment: There is a implicit conversion named option2Iterable defined in Option object, which can converse Option to Iterable.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: Yes, it is. I've updated the answer to explain how that works.

Comment: @stew: Thanks for the edit. My copy-and-paste-fu failed me. :-P

Comment: @ruakh I still think it's wrong to say that `A` "is-a" `B` because an implicit conversion `A => B` exists. I've added some more details to clarify the answer - hope this is OK.